# Given an element in a quotient group $G/H$, find an element with the same order in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

### Problem

> A finite abelian group $G$ has an element $g$ of order $n$, which generates the subgroup $H = \langle g \rangle$.  Let $\gamma$ be an element of order $m$ in $G/H$.  Show that there exists an element $x \in G$ such that $\lvert x \rvert = \lvert \gamma \rvert = m$.

I copied my instructor's solution, but I missed the last part, and I can't proceed from what's on my notebook.

> Suppose that $x_0 \in G$ such that $\overline{x_0} = \gamma$.  Since $\lvert \gamma \rvert = m$, $x_0^m \in H = \langle g \rangle$, and we denote $x_0^m = g^k$.  Divide $k$ by $m$ to get $k = mq + r$ with $r \in \{0,\dots,m-1\}$.
>   \begin{align}
> x_0^m &= g^k = g^{mq + r} \\
> g^r &= x_0^m g^{-mq} = \left(x_0 g^{-q} \right)^m
> \end{align}
>   *We want to show $r=0$.*
>   Let $x' = x_0 g^{-q}$.  Observe that $\overline{\mathstrut x'}=\overline{\mathstrut x_0}=\gamma$ and $m \mid \lvert x' \rvert$ because $$e = x'^{\mathstrut \lvert x' \rvert} = x_0^{\mathstrut \lvert x' \rvert} \underbrace{g^{\mathstrut -q \lvert x' \rvert}}_{\in H}.$$
>   $$\therefore \lvert (x')^m \rvert = \frac{\lvert x' \rvert}{\gcd(m,\lvert x' \rvert)} = \frac{\lvert x' \rvert}{m}$$

I don't know how to continue with this.

Comment: Hint: Chose your $x_0$ in the beginning such that $k$ is minimal. Then you'll see that $r$ must be zero after line four already.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain So you mean before choosing $x_0$, we should fix $k = \min\limits_{x \in \pi^{-1}(\gamma)} \{\mathrm{ord}_H (x^m)\}$ first?

Comment: That is precisely what I suggest, yes.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain I've made a mistake due to hunger 2 hours ago.  It should be $$k = \min\{k' \in \Bbb N^* \mid \exists x \in \pi^{-1}(\gamma) \text{ s.t. } x^m = g^{k'}\}.$$  Then we choose $x_0 \in \pi^{-1} (\gamma)$ such that $x_0^m = g^k$, and we divide $k$ by $m$ so that $k = mq + r$ with $0 \le r < m$.  But if $k < m$, then $r = k$, so we can't make $r$ smaller than $k$, and the minimality of $k$ can't be applied to $$g^r = x_0^m g^{-mq} = \left(x_0 g^{-q} \right)^m = \left(x' \right)^m$$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Instead of posting a lot of comments and running from one answer to another, I think would be more useful to edit the question starting by explaining what's the role of $g$ and $n$ in this story.

Comment: @user26857 Their role is stated in the beginning, and it has never changed.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I'll take our comment as a less inspired joke. Hagen von Eitzen's answer shows why.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for your comments.  I wrote $g$ and $n$ simply because they are present in the question.  From his answer, in fact they are unnecessary in proving the result stated in the title.

Comment: I think your instructor wanted to prove something else. Otherwise didn't add so many extra-conditions. (As someone remarked in a comment, he likely wanted $x$ in the same coset as $\gamma$.)

Comment: @user26857 Yes, you're right.  That's on the paper, but I omitted that in the post.  As you can see from Jorge Fernández Hidalgo's answer, if the statement will be false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This argument seems overly complicated (and the conditions overly strict).

**Claim.** Let $G$ be a finite group and $H\lhd G$ a normal subgroup. Let $\gamma\in H$ be an element of order $m$. Then $G$ has an element $x$ of order $m$.

*Proof.* Let $\pi\colon G\to G/H$ denote the canonical projection. Pick $x_0\in G$ with $\pi({x_0})=\gamma$. Then $\langle x_0\rangle$ is a cyclic group with $\pi(\langle x_0\rangle)=\langle \gamma\rangle$, hence is a cyclic group of order divisible by $m$. We know that such a cyclic group contains an element of order $m$. $\square$

Comment: yeah, this works. But I think the goal is for $x$ to be in the same coset as $\gamma$

Comment: Much cleaner than the instructor's proof in the OP (+1). Minor typo: $\gamma \in G/H$.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation!
@Bungo Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $[x_0]=\gamma$.

It means that $$x_0^m=g^k$$

for some $k$ becuse $x_0^m$ is the unit in the quotient. Now just elevate to the smallest number $t$ making $n|kt$. We get $$(x_0^t)^m = 1$$ thus $ord (x_0^t) \leq m$. Now it can't be strictly less than $m$ because you would find that $g$ has order less than $n$. We were looking for $x:=x_0^t$.

Comment: yeah, this works. But I think the goal is for $x$ to be in the same coset as $\gamma$

Comment: I don't understand the second last sentence.  If we take $m'=\mathrm{ord}(x_0^t) < m$, then what will happen?
$$1=(x_0^t)^{m'}=x_0^{tm'}=x_0^{q'm + r'} = g^{q'k}x_0^{r'}$$
I have to show $x_0^{r'} \in H$?  Am I getting the wrong way?

Comment: Simply "apply class" now: $[1]=[g^wx_0^r]=[x_0^r]=[x_0]^r=\gamma^r$ but $\gamma$ has order $m$ and $r<m$ because it comes from euclidean division.

Answer (score 1):

Is this true? Consider $\mathbb Z_4$ and the subgroup $\{0,2\}$. Notice that the odd coset has order $2$ but no element in it has order $2$, they all have order $4$. It is true when $(n,m)=1$ however.

Comment: I think the same, by the way it is not requested that $[x]=\gamma$ if I'm not messing up.

Comment: Where are you reading the requirement that $x \in \gamma$?

Comment: because of the way the proof is pursued, if we could show that $r=0$ then we would be done, sadly this is not always the case.

Comment: Thanks.  That's the only answer that I've understood now.  I'll read the others later.

Comment: the other proofs are correct, I think that the problem is that the teacher wants the element of G to be in the same coset as gamma, which makes the proof harder than jus tfinding an arbitrary element of order m.

Comment: @Bungo I'm sorry to have this condition missed in the question.  Luckily, you get it, but I'm not going to change this question due to this counterexample and other existing answers.

Comment: wait, so we have $(n,m)=1$ ?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I mean the existence of $x \in G$ such that $\color{\red}{[x] = \gamma}$ and $\lvert x \rvert = \lvert \gamma \rvert = m$.  I *don't* know how this will imply $(n,m) = 1$.  But anyways, this counterexample satisfies the question, no matter the $\color{\red}{\text{missing condition}}$ is present or not.