# Find an element of order 2 given that there is one in the quotient.

Tags: group-theory

From an [old exam](https://tbp.berkeley.edu/exams/921/download/):

> Let $G$ be a group (not necessarily finite) and let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Assume that $H$ is finite and that $\left|H\right|$ is odd. Prove that if $aH$ is an element of order 2 in $G/H$ then there exists an element $a_1 \in G$ or order 2 with $aH = a_1H$.

I have no idea where to begin. I feel like I should be using Lagrange's Theorem or Cauchy's Theorem, except they do not help with an infinite group. The other idea was to look at the preimage of $\left<a\right>$ under the projection homomorphism, e.g. let $a_1 \in \pi^{-1}(aH)$ so $\left<a_1\right> \cong \left<aH\right>$ (as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075075/given-an-element-in-a-quotient-group-g-h-find-an-element-with-the-same-order#comment4261860_2075098)). But it seems that I am missing something, because I am not making use of the fact that $H$ is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $aH$ has order $2$, $a^2\in H$. Try to use this together with the fact that $H$ has odd order to find an element of order $2$ in $aH$. (Hint: consider some power of $a$.)

Comment: Note also that, while $G$ is not necessarily finite, $\langle a,H\rangle$ is, and everything is happening "inside" there, so you can also apply standard theorems to this group, though that is perhaps less in the spirit of the question.

Comment: I still do not get it. So $\left<a\right> \le H$ has odd order at least 2. But I don't see what can be inferred about the order of $a$ in $G$.

Comment: No, $\langle a\rangle\leq H$ is not true, since $a\notin H$. On the other hand, $a^2\in H$. So the order of $a^2$ is odd. What does that tell you about the order of $a$?

Comment: The highest power of 2 in the order of $a$ is $1$?

Comment: Right, $a$ has order twice an odd number. Now, find the element of order $2$ in $\langle a \rangle$. (Every cyclic group of even order has a unique such element.) Try to show that it is contained in $aH$.